# Changing the single header field in HTTP request in libcurl

Tags: http, http-headers, libcurl

I have written a HTTP client program. In that I get the data from another process and add it in the POST field of the Request. But libcurl uses content type as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.
But i want to just change the content-type to `binary`, how should i change only `content-type` it without need of manually changing of other fields like content-length, agent.. etc ?

```
              curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
              curl =  curl_easy_init(); 
              curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, shell_machine);  //shell_machine is xxx.xx.xx.xx:8080/xxx
              curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, buf);    // buf is my post data
              curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, post_size);  // size of my                             post data

              curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "libcurl-agent/1.0");

              res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTHTTPHEADER) is your friend. Usage is shown in the [httpcustomheader.c](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/httpcustomheader.html) example.